# Testing a front-end with Javascript and SVG using Rspec, Capybara and Selenium - best approach?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, selenium, svg, capybara

I am developing an application using Ruby on Rails and am doing some testing with RSpec, Capybara and Selenium.

I'm fairly new to testing (unit and integration) and was wondering what the best way to approach testing a front-end built with javascript is.  Javascript is used to allow the user to place and manipulate SVG elements in a diagram (such as position, dimensions, colour, etc.). These elements are saved to the database with their properties so that when the user reloads the diagram everything is as it was.

So far, for testing interaction with standard user features (e.g. signing up, logging in, viewing the list of diagrams etc.) my tests consist of creating a user and destroying a user before and after each test respectively, e.g.:

```
require 'spec_helper'
require_relative 'integration_test_helper'

describe "Diagrams" do

  include IntegrationTestHelper
  before :all do
    @test_user = Factory.create(:user)
  end

  after :all do
    @test_user.destroy
  end

  context "authenticated user" do
    before :each do
      visit new_user_session_path
      login(@test_user)
    end

    it "should be taken to the diagrams index page" do
      visit diagrams_path
      #page.should have_content "Your Diagrams"
      page.should have_content diagrams.index.title
    end

    it "should list the user's diagrams" do
      diagram = Factory.create(:diagram, :user => @test_user)
      visit diagrams_path
      page.should have_content(diagram.title)
      diagram.destroy
    end
```

...and here is a test I wrote to detect that creating and clicking on a link to a new diagram showed the appropriate container div and initial SVG tag on the screen (using Selenium):

```
    it "should create a diagram and go to the new diagram when clicked", :js => true do
      visit diagrams_path
      find("#btn_create_new_diagram").click

      within("form#new_diagram") do 
        fill_in "diagram_title", :with => "Test diagram"
      end

      click_button diagrams.new.create
      click_on "Test diagram"
      page.should have_content "Test diagram"
      find("#container")
      find("*[name()='svg']")
    end

  end
end
```

For testing the diagram editor, would I be better to do something like create diagram elements in the database and check that they display appropriately on the screen, or could I test actual user interaction such as actually placing and manipulating diagram elements (I imagine this would be difficult and possibly quite brittle since it might rely on mouse co-ordinates etc)? Also, do I want to be creating and destroying a diagram before and after each test respectively? I would prefer to test constructing a fairly large diagram but I'm worried this could result in some long and messy tests.